# How to neglect a a block of bits while adding two binary numbers at bit level

Tags: c++

I have been assigned a project on binary arithmetic at the bit level. I have made a function which successfully adds two binary numbers ignoring the overflow. For some reason , I want to make it more flexible by passing an argument to ignore n bits of bits from a number.

For instance, I want to  neglect the rightmost two bits of a and add it to b.

```
         a=111011

         b= 101         
        +---------
          1001111
```

Here's my function definition.

```html
void add( bool reg[], bool arr[], int sizereg, int sizearr, int cut)

{
int i=sizereg-1-cut;
int j=sizereg-sizearr;

bool  carry=0,dummy;



for (i; i>=j-cut ; i--)
  {

     dummy=reg[i]; 
     reg[i]= (!reg[i]) && (arr[i-j] !=carry) || reg[i] && (arr[i-j]==carry);
     carry=(arr[i-j] &&dummy) || (dummy&&carry) || (arr[i-j]&&carry);
  }

while (carry && (i+1))

{     
    dummy=reg[i];
    reg[i]=(carry!=reg[i]);
    carry=(carry==dummy);
    i--;
}
```

My program works for cut=0, for nonzero values of cut, it doesn't give the desired result. How do I correctly use cut in order to  neglect (cut) number of bits from the reg array

PS: I don't want to use Leftshift technique.

Comment: what do you mean you dont want to use a leftshift technique? You dont want to use the operator `<<`?  You could easily write code to simulate left shifting/right shifting

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are confident you can right a version of `add()` for which the `cut` is 0. Then, you can write two functions. The first function just implements the `add()` assuming the `cut` is 0.

```
// Add reg and arr (cut is 0)
void add( bool reg[], bool arr[], int sizereg, int sizearr )
{
    //...
}
```

The second function that has `cut` calls the first function, adjusting the arguments in such a way that the `cut` can be treated as 0. If the `cut` is on the higher order indices, you simply need to reduce the size. If the `cut` is on the lower order indices, then you also have to advance the pointer.

```
// cut > 0 means cutting the higher indices.
// cut < 0 means cutting the lower indices.
void add( bool reg[], bool arr[], int sizereg, int sizearr, int cut )
{
    if (cut < 0) {
        cut = -cut;
        reg += cut;
    }
    add(reg, arr, sizereg - cut, sizearr);
}
```